# How to reverse year over year change to fill the nan values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, the `Value Col` ends in 2022-12-31.

```
              Value Col    Factor
    2022-01-31  0.021       5%
    2022-02-28  0.020       4%
    2022-03-31  0.019       3%
    2022-04-30  0.018       2%
    2022-05-31  0.017       9%
    2022-06-30  0.016       7%
    2022-07-31  0.015       7%
    2022-08-31  0.014       5%
    2022-09-30  0.013       -6%
    2022-10-31  0.018       4%
    2022-11-30  0.020       -8%
    2022-12-31  0.015       7%
    2023-01-31  NaN         5%
    2023-02-28  NaN         4%
    2023-03-31  NaN         3%
    2023-04-30  NaN         4%
    2023-05-31  NaN         9%
    2023-06-30  NaN         -6%
    2023-07-31  NaN         7%
    2023-08-31  NaN         5%
    2023-09-30  NaN         6%
    2023-10-31  NaN         -4%
    2023-11-30  NaN         2%
    2023-12-31  NaN         1%
    2024-01-31  NaN         5%
    2024-02-28  NaN         4%
    2024-03-31  NaN         6%
    2024-04-30  NaN         2%
    2024-05-31  NaN         -9%
    2024-06-30  NaN         8%
    2024-07-31  NaN         6%
    2024-08-31  NaN         -7%
    2024-09-30  NaN         6%
    2024-10-31  NaN         4%
    2024-11-30  NaN         2%
    2024-12-31  NaN         -1%
```

And there is a `Factor` column which shows the percentage; how much the NaN value should be  filled with compared to the same month of the previous year value.
For example, df.loc['2023-04-30', 'Value Col'] should be 0,01872. (value on **2022**-04-30 is 0.018 and factor on **2023**-04-30 is 4%. So, 0.018 + 0.018*4%  =  0.01872.

I seems to me a reverse of `pct_change()` function of pandas. But I could not figure it out how to solve it. Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: How large is the dataframe? If small enough, a simple loop, while not efficient, might be good enough (and won't slow you down).

Comment: A for loop can be a quick fix for the issue, I have already tired it and it worked. But I was looking for more pandas way(if any).

Comment: For Future reference, (if anyone looking for this question)

The brilliant answers provided by mozway and @jezrael use for loop because the NaN should be filled depending on the value of the exact previous year. So until now, the most efficient way is to fill the NaN values one year by another using a for loop.

Comment: @EMT actually you can also use another solution without loop, I'll update if you want

Comment: @mozway I will be more than glad to see that as a second solution of your current answer. Just to enrich my and other learner's knowledge.

Comment: I updated my answer for the general logic, I want however to double check something

Comment: @EMT here it is ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`pandas.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) and repeat the operation for each year:

```
# ensure we have a datetime index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# extract the factor as float 4% -> 1.04
factor = df['Factor'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float).div(100).add(1)

# for each year, compute the value from the preceding year
for year in range(len(df.index.year.unique())-1):
    df.loc[df['Value Col'].isna(), 'Value Col'] = (
                           df['Value Col']
                           .shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))
                           .mul(factor)
                         )
```

Output:

```
            Value Col Factor
2022-01-31   0.021000     5%
2022-02-28   0.020000     4%
2022-03-31   0.019000     3%
2022-04-30   0.018000     2%
2022-05-31   0.017000     9%
2022-06-30   0.016000     7%
2022-07-31   0.015000     7%
2022-08-31   0.014000     5%
2022-09-30   0.013000    -6%
2022-10-31   0.018000     4%
2022-11-30   0.020000    -8%
2022-12-31   0.015000     7%
2023-01-31   0.022050     5%
2023-02-28   0.020800     4%
2023-03-31   0.019570     3%
2023-04-30   0.018720     4%
2023-05-31   0.018530     9%
2023-06-30   0.015040    -6%
2023-07-31   0.016050     7%
2023-08-31   0.014700     5%
2023-09-30   0.013780     6%
2023-10-31   0.017280    -4%
2023-11-30   0.020400     2%
2023-12-31   0.015150     1%
2024-01-31   0.023153     5%
2024-02-28   0.021632     4%
2024-03-31   0.020744     6%
2024-04-30   0.019094     2%
2024-05-31   0.016862    -9%
2024-06-30   0.016243     8%
2024-07-31   0.017013     6%
2024-08-31   0.013671    -7%
2024-09-30   0.014607     6%
2024-10-31   0.017971     4%
2024-11-30   0.020808     2%
2024-12-31   0.014998    -1%
```

##### alternative

You should also be able to compute the cumulated product of the factors ([`groupby.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumprod.html)) and multiply the forward filled values ([`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html)):

```
group = df.index.month
factor = (df['Factor'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float).div(100).add(1)
          .where(df['Value Col'].isna())
          .groupby(group).cumprod()
         )
df.loc[df['Value Col'].isna(), 'Value Col'] = (
   df['Value Col'].groupby(group).ffill()
   .mul(factor)
)
```

*NB. this requires the dates to be sorted in ascending order.*

Intermediates:

```
            Value Col Factor  group  initial  factor
2022-01-31   0.021000     5%      1    0.021     NaN
2022-02-28   0.020000     4%      2    0.020     NaN
2022-03-31   0.019000     3%      3    0.019     NaN
2022-04-30   0.018000     2%      4    0.018     NaN
2022-05-31   0.017000     9%      5    0.017     NaN
2022-06-30   0.016000     7%      6    0.016     NaN
2022-07-31   0.015000     7%      7    0.015     NaN
2022-08-31   0.014000     5%      8    0.014     NaN
2022-09-30   0.013000    -6%      9    0.013     NaN
2022-10-31   0.018000     4%     10    0.018     NaN
2022-11-30   0.020000    -8%     11    0.020     NaN
2022-12-31   0.015000     7%     12    0.015     NaN
2023-01-31   0.022050     5%      1    0.021  1.0500
2023-02-28   0.020800     4%      2    0.020  1.0400
2023-03-31   0.019570     3%      3    0.019  1.0300
2023-04-30   0.018720     4%      4    0.018  1.0400
2023-05-31   0.018530     9%      5    0.017  1.0900
2023-06-30   0.015040    -6%      6    0.016  0.9400
2023-07-31   0.016050     7%      7    0.015  1.0700
2023-08-31   0.014700     5%      8    0.014  1.0500
2023-09-30   0.013780     6%      9    0.013  1.0600
2023-10-31   0.017280    -4%     10    0.018  0.9600
2023-11-30   0.020400     2%     11    0.020  1.0200
2023-12-31   0.015150     1%     12    0.015  1.0100
2024-01-31   0.023153     5%      1    0.021  1.1025
2024-02-28   0.021632     4%      2    0.020  1.0816
2024-03-31   0.020744     6%      3    0.019  1.0918
2024-04-30   0.019094     2%      4    0.018  1.0608
2024-05-31   0.016862    -9%      5    0.017  0.9919
2024-06-30   0.016243     8%      6    0.016  1.0152
2024-07-31   0.017013     6%      7    0.015  1.1342
2024-08-31   0.013671    -7%      8    0.014  0.9765
2024-09-30   0.014607     6%      9    0.013  1.1236
2024-10-31   0.017971     4%     10    0.018  0.9984
2024-11-30   0.020808     2%     11    0.020  1.0404
2024-12-31   0.014998    -1%     12    0.015  0.9999
```

Comment: Second solution is just awesome. I want to share one important bug (?!) of pandas that, when using `df[any_column].shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))`, pandas fail to solve leap year issue. The shift of 1 year date shows from `2024-02-29` to `2023-02-29` (instead of `2023-02-28`). @mozway

Comment: @EMT to avoid these issues, better work with monthly periods (`df.index = df.index.to_period('M')`) rather than dates. The code should be the same with the last approach. For the loop you probably would have to shift using `df.shift(12)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop for replace missing values in next year:

```
df['f'] = df['Factor'].str.extract(r'(-*\d+)').astype(int).div(100)

years = df.index.year

for y in years.unique():
    
    #original year
    m = years == y
    #next year
    m1 = years == y + 1
    #change DatetimeIndex
    df1 = df[m].rename(lambda x: x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1))
    #count new values and replace NaNs
    s = df1['Value Col'].add(df.loc[m1, 'f'].mul(df1['Value Col']))
    df.loc[m1, 'Value Col'] = df.loc[m1, 'Value Col'].fillna(s)
```

---

```
print (df)
            Value Col Factor     f
2022-01-31   0.021000     5%  0.05
2022-02-28   0.020000     4%  0.04
2022-03-31   0.019000     3%  0.03
2022-04-30   0.018000     2%  0.02
2022-05-31   0.017000     9%  0.09
2022-06-30   0.016000     7%  0.07
2022-07-31   0.015000     7%  0.07
2022-08-31   0.014000     5%  0.05
2022-09-30   0.013000    -6% -0.06
2022-10-31   0.018000     4%  0.04
2022-11-30   0.020000    -8% -0.08
2022-12-31   0.015000     7%  0.07
2023-01-31   0.022050     5%  0.05
2023-02-28   0.020800     4%  0.04
2023-03-31   0.019570     3%  0.03
2023-04-30   0.018720     4%  0.04
2023-05-31   0.018530     9%  0.09
2023-06-30   0.015040    -6% -0.06
2023-07-31   0.016050     7%  0.07
2023-08-31   0.014700     5%  0.05
2023-09-30   0.013780     6%  0.06
2023-10-31   0.017280    -4% -0.04
2023-11-30   0.020400     2%  0.02
2023-12-31   0.015150     1%  0.01
2024-01-31   0.023152     5%  0.05
2024-02-28   0.021632     4%  0.04
2024-03-31   0.020744     6%  0.06
2024-04-30   0.019094     2%  0.02
2024-05-31   0.016862    -9% -0.09
2024-06-30   0.016243     8%  0.08
2024-07-31   0.017013     6%  0.06
2024-08-31   0.013671    -7% -0.07
2024-09-30   0.014607     6%  0.06
2024-10-31   0.017971     4%  0.04
2024-11-30   0.020808     2%  0.02
2024-12-31   0.014998    -1% -0.01
```